# Localization of an integer quotient is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R:=\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$ be our ring, $f: \mathbb{Z}\to R$ be the canonical quotient map (i.e. $f$ sends an element to its equivalence class) and $q$ be the ideal generated by $f(3 +24\mathbb{Z})$. I want to show that $R_q:=(R\setminus q)^{-1}R$ is a field.

My Ideas:
Since $f(3 +24\mathbb{Z})=f(3)$, we get $q=3\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$, hence $q$ is a prime ideal. 
Moreover it's sufficient to show that $R_q$ without the zero element is a group with respect to $*$ ($*$ is the multiplication sign), because of $R_q$ is a ring (in particular unitial and commutative).
But now I'm really stuck, because I don't see exactly how the elements of $R_q$ look like without doing long explicit computation of the equivalence classes of $R_q$.

edit: I did some corrections, I hope it's now more clear.

Comment: Your notation $f(3 + \mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z})$ does not really make sense. Do you mean the ideal in $\mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}$ generated by the image of $3$?

Comment: Do you actually mean $R_q:=(R\setminus q)^{-1}R$? This slash (/) is usually reserved for quotients, not set difference.

Comment: I did some corrections, I hope it's now more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title statement "localization of an integer quotient is a field" is incorrect in general.

For example when $n$ is not squarefree (as is the case for $24=2^3\cdot 3$) then the localization at the prime which isn't squarefree contains nonzero nilpotent elements, so it is not a field. In the $n=24$ case, localizing at $2$ demonstrates this: if you localize at the complement of $(2)$ then $3$ becomes a unit, but then $3\cdot 8=24=0$ implies $8=0$.

However, with what that teaches us, I think you'll be able to solve your problem :) With the special choice of localizing at $(3)$ in your example, things are going to work out.

Here is a good approach. After you do the localization at the set $S=R\setminus(3)$, then $S^{-1}R$ is a local ring with unique maximal ideal generated by $3$ right? If you show that this ideal is zero, then the localization is a commutative ring with only two trivial ideals (and that is a field.)

Work to show that the ideal generated by $3$ in the localization is zero. Of course, the fact that $24=0$ and $2$ is a unit plays an important role in this.

Comment: Localizing at the complement of $(3)$, we see that 8 is invertible. Since $3\cdot8=24=0$, hence $3=0$. We deduce $(3)=(0)$. Since $(R_q,(3))$ is local, any ideal generated by non-zero element $a$ has to be $R_q$, which implies that $a$ is invertible. Since the set of invertible elements is group with respect to the multiplication, wet get the desired.

Comment: Although this seems right, localization is a bit mysterious for me. I often ask myself how "well-behaved" is it (i.e. it behaves like integers located at the complement of $(0)$, which is I think isomorphic to the rationals? Maybe if R is an integral domain?). Considering your example of localizing at (2), for me it seems quite mysterious that $8=0$, although I understand completely your reasoning. But Can I see, what are the "surprises" of the localization by considering the original ring (e.g. which elements are suddenly equal to $0$, are there any other "misbehaved" surprises?).

Comment: Maybe more general, in which way behaves the localization of ring in other way as the original ring? In which do they behave the same? One point is surely, that elements of $S$ are invertible in the localization.

Comment: @bjn Good questions :) Well, what do you think about this: in the localization, the original multiplication rules what goes on in the top and bottom of the fractions: $\frac{a}{b}\frac{c}{d}=\frac{ac}{bd}$. As for "surprises," you may be completely surprised if the set you're localizing at contains $0$: then the localization will collapse to zero!

Comment: @bjn Localizations for domains is a little easier to think about. This is because the original domain injects into the localization, and the localization is contained in the field of quotients of the domain. The localizations are then just special subrings of the field of quotients that are easy to identify.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If $S$ (i.e. the set we localize at) contains $0$, we get for an arbitrary element $\frac{x}{s}=\{(t,y)\in S\times R: \exists u \in S:utx=usy\}$, so $0tx=0=0sy$ for any $t,y,x,s$, hence there is only one element. I have more concrete questions: How many elements have $(S)^{-1}R}$, where $R,S$ is chosen as in my first post? Are always $\frac{x}{1}$,$\frac{y}{1}$ for $x,y\in R$ distinct, if $x,y$ is distinct?

Comment: @bjn Potentially $\frac{x}{1}$ and $\frac{y}{1}$ can be equal even if $x\neq y$. We only know that $xu=yu$ for some $u\in S$. For example, if $uv=0$ for some $0\neq v\in R$, then $xu=(x+v)u$, so $\frac{x}{1}$ and $\frac{x+v}{1}$ are equal but $x$ and $x+v$ are not. If $u$ is regular, then you can cancel it from $xu=yu$ and get $x=y$, so it is true in the case of domains, and more generally when $S$ just has regular elements in it.

Comment: @bjn Actually now that I think about it, we already gave a concrete example :)  $\frac{8}{1}$ and $\frac{0}{1}$ are equal in $\Bbb Z/(24)$ after you localize at the complement of $(2)$.

Comment: Now, localization comes less mysterious;). Avoiding a long computation, I can't still see how many elements has $S^{-1}R$? Moreover is there a systematic way to find all $x\in R$ such that $sx=0$ for $s\in S$?(Again, $R,S$ are defined as in my first post)